# Applying geolocation in phonegap doesn't work

Tags: android, html, geolocation, phonegap

I'm rather new to this and currently working on my first app (for a school project). I followed this https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/ tutorial. When I open the project in the browser (on a pc) it gives the coordinates but once installed (though phonegap) on my phone nothing seems to happen. Also the implementation with google maps does not seem to work (also not on the pc). Can any of you help me or redirect me to easy to follow guids?

These are the sources I looked at as well:

https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/map-geolocation/

https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-activating-geolocation-on-mobile-devices

https://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-mobile-web-a-guide-geolocation-api

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/geolocation/geolocation.getCurrentPosition.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

```
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML =
      "Latitude: " +
      position.coords.latitude +
      "<br>Longitude: " +
      position.coords.longitude;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>

    <head>
    ...
    <script>

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

                    function onDeviceReady() {
                        //onDeviceReaddy
                        initMap(); //Google map 
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayAndWatch, locError);
                    }
                    // user Current Position
                function displayAndWatch(position) {
                    setCurrentPosition(position);
                    watchCurrentPosition();
                }

                function setCurrentPosition(pos) {
                    var image = 'img/ic_CurrentLocationmap.png';

                    currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        icon: image,
                        map: map,
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                            pos.coords.latitude,
                            pos.coords.longitude
                        ),
                        title: "Current Location"
                    });
                    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
                        pos.coords.latitude,
                        pos.coords.longitude
                    ));
                }

                function watchCurrentPosition() {
                    var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                        function (position) {
                            setMarkerPosition(
                                currentPositionMarker,
                                position
                            );
                        });
                }

                function setMarkerPosition(marker, position) {
                    marker.setPosition(
                        new google.maps.LatLng(
                            position.coords.latitude,
                            position.coords.longitude)
                    );
                    var center = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    }
                    map.setCenter(center);  
                }
                function locError(error) {
                    // the current position could not be located
                }
                });
    <script>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    ...
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=******(Your API Key)">
        </script>
    </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response but I do not get it to work. I have this now:

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Huisartspraktijk app</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- /jquery links en scripts. NIET VERWIJDEREN!! -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
/* css styes for the maps */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

<!-- Script for the geolocation, Stack Overflow -->
<script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

                    function onDeviceReady() {
                        //onDeviceReaddy
                        initMap(); //Google map 
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayAndWatch, locError);
                    }
                    // user Current Position
                function displayAndWatch(position) {
                    setCurrentPosition(position);
                    watchCurrentPosition();
                }

                function setCurrentPosition(pos) {
                    var image = 'img/ic_CurrentLocationmap.png';

                    currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        icon: image,
                        map: map,
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                            pos.coords.latitude,
                            pos.coords.longitude
                        ),
                        title: "Current Location"
                    });
                    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
                        pos.coords.latitude,
                        pos.coords.longitude
                    ));
                }

                function watchCurrentPosition() {
                    var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                        function (position) {
                            setMarkerPosition(
                                currentPositionMarker,
                                position
                            );
                        });
                }

                function setMarkerPosition(marker, position) {
                    marker.setPosition(
                        new google.maps.LatLng(
                            position.coords.latitude,
                            position.coords.longitude)
                    );
                    var center = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    }
                    map.setCenter(center);  
                }
                function locError(error) {
                    // the current position could not be located
                }
                });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- The mobile page in html5, within this page there is a DIV containing the Java Script to summon google maps -->
<div data-role="page" id="mobiel">
 <!-- /header -->
         <div data-role="header">
            <h1>SPOED</h1>
  <div data-role="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#main">Mainpage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chat">Chat met de arts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#consult">Consultaanvraag</a></li>
    <li><a href="#doorverwijzing">Doorverwijzing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bloedonderzoek">Bloedonderzoek</a></li>
    <li><a href="#berichten">Berichten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#epd">EPD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#medicijnen">Mijn medicijnen</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
        </div>
   <!-- /content -->
        <div role="main" class="ui-content" align="center">
  <h2> "Ga naar deze medische post. Men is op de hoogte van uw komst" </h2>
  <div style="background-color: lightyellow">
   <br>
   <h3> Huisartsenpraktijk Gideonse en Boekhout </h3>
   <p>Meteorenstraat 4<br>
   2024 RK, Haarlem</p>
   <p>Telefoon<br>
   023 - 525 36 00 </p>
   <p>Keuze 1: Spoed <br>
   Keuze 2: Herhaalrecepten <br>
   Keuze 3: Assistentie</p>
   <br>
  <!-- In this DIV you will find a small Java Script for summoning Google maps. But some how it won't work, Google maps won't show within this DIV. -->
   <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
       zoom: 8
     });
      }
    </script>

   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBRewVX3nHmzN6KDiT5g5ruUCINH4wERaQ&callback=initMap"
   async defer></script>

  </div>

  <a href="#spoedEisend" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Terug</a>
 </div>
   <!-- /footer -->
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h2>&copy; 2019 Huisartsapp</h2>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```